# Using nodejs async and request module

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, httprequest, async.js

I'm trying to use async and request module together but i don't understand how the callbacks get passed. My code is

```
var fetch = function(file, cb) {
    return request(file, cb);
};

async.map(['file1', 'file2', 'file3'], fetch, function(err, resp, body) {
    // is this function passed as an argument to _fetch_ 
    // or is it excecuted as a callback at the end of all the request?
    // if so how do i pass a callback to the _fetch_ function
    if(!err) console.log(body);
});
```

I'm trying to fetch 3 files in order and concatenate the results. My head is stuck in callbacks I tryed and the different combinations I could think of. Google wasn't much help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Request is asynchronous function, it does not return something, when its job is done, it calls back. From [request examples](https://github.com/mikeal/request#examples), you should do something like:

```
var fetch = function(file,cb){
     request.get(file, function(err,response,body){
           if ( err){
                 cb(err);
           } else {
                 cb(null, body); // First param indicates error, null=> no error
           }
     });
}
async.map(["file1", "file2", "file3"], fetch, function(err, results){
    if ( err){
       // either file1, file2 or file3 has raised an error, so you should not use results and handle the error
    } else {
       // results[0] -> "file1" body
       // results[1] -> "file2" body
       // results[2] -> "file3" body
    }
});
```

Comment: code working and very easy to understand what I did wrong now :) thanks

Comment: Your link to the examples does not show any callbacks. All they do is log to the console.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, the `fetch` function will be called three times, once for each of the file names in the array passed as the first parameter to `async.map`.  A second, callback parameter will also be passed into `fetch`, but that callback is provided by the async framework and you must call it when your `fetch` function has completed its work, providing its results to that callback as the second parameter.  The callback you provide as the third parameter to `async.map` will be called when all three of the `fetch` calls have called the callback provided to them.

See https://github.com/caolan/async#map

So to answer your specific question in the code, the callback function you provide is executed as a callback at then end of all requests.  If you need to pass a callback to `fetch` you'd do something like this:

```
async.map([['file1', 'file2', 'file3'], function(value, callback) {
    fetch(value, <your result processing callback goes here>);
}, ...
```